# ¿Como puedo ponerle una licencia a mi proyecto en Github, si cuando lo cree no le puse licencia?

Tags: git, github

Quiero ponerle unas licencias a mis proyectos ya creados en Github pero cuando los cree no les puse y ahora no se como ponerselas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solo debes crear el archivo de licencia y hacer un commit al repositorio.

Crea el archivo de licencia con un block de notas e ingresas el texto de la licencia.

Luego en la raiz de la carpeta local del proyecto:

git add .
git commit -m "Licencia"
git push origin master

eso es todo

Comment: ¿Como lo creo? supongo que es desde Git, de antemano muchas gracias

Comment: Creas el archivo en tu repositorio, como crearias cualquier archivo.